# How to get values from a TextBox and apply a format automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, split, textbox

Below is my place holder in which the values are hard-coded:

```
var abc = string.Format($"{123456} {123456} {12345} {123456789012345} {12345678901234567890123} {1234} {1234} {123} {1234567890123} {123456789012345} {1} {123456789012345} 
{123} {12} {12345678901234567890} {1} {1234}");

File.WriteAllText(
    FilePath + "\\CDR-" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss") + ".txt", abc);
```

But I want to get values from the TextBox automatically in these placeholders.

Suppose below is my TextBox and its value:

```
123456 123456 12345 123456789012345 12345678901234567890123 
1234 1234 123 1234567890123 123456789012345 1 123456789012345 
123 12 12345678901234567890 1 1234
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692613/how-to-get-textbox-value-in-placeholder-on-code-behind. It may be duplicate, go to this link, my that helps you.

Comment: i am not getting what I want.

Comment: i want first value from text box to go to first place holder, 2nd value to second place holder, 3rd value to third placeholder and so on and on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the input string using the sequence separator (it appears to be a white space here), and use the string array generated by [string.Spilt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) as the input of the `string.Format()` method.

Something like this:

```
string filePath = @"[Some Path]";
string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split();
var format = string.Format(
    "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11} {12} {13} {14} {15} {16}",
    values);

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(filePath, 
    "CDR-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss") + ".txt"), 
    format);
```

If you have a different separator, specify it as a parameter of the `Split()` method.

The white space is the predefined character. No need to specify it in this case. With different symbols:

- A single character: `[someString].Split(',');`
- More than one: `[someString].Split(new[] {',', '+'});`
- Strings:  `[someString].Split(new[] { ",", "+" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: yes i want to split it by one space. Should I write this in parameters.string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split(" ");

Comment: The white space (`char(32)`) is the predefined character. You don't need to insert it. I'll make an edit to show you how to insert different symbols.