# Combining several functions into one function

Tags: vb.net

I have these functions:

```
Private Sub AddToEventDetails(ByRef sEvent As My_GoogleEvent, strLabelID As String, ByRef dictLabels As Dictionary(Of String, String), strValue As String)
    Dim strFormatString = dictLabels(strLabelID)
    Dim strText = String.Format(strFormatString, strValue)

    ' strText can never be empty because it now includes the label. So test against strValue instead
    If (strValue <> "") Then
        sEvent.strEventDetails += strText & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddToEventDetails(ByRef sEvent As My_GoogleEvent, strLabelID As String, ByRef dictLabels As Dictionary(Of String, String), strValue1 As String, strValue2 As String)
    Dim strFormatString = dictLabels(strLabelID)
    Dim strText = String.Format(strFormatString, strValue1, strValue2)

    If (strText <> "") Then
        sEvent.strEventDetails += strText & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddToEventDetails(ByRef sEvent As My_GoogleEvent, strLabelID As String, ByRef dictLabels As Dictionary(Of String, String), strValue1 As String, strValue2 As String, strValue3 As String)
    Dim strFormatString = dictLabels(strLabelID)
    Dim strText = String.Format(strFormatString, strValue1, strValue2, strValue3)

    If (strText <> "") Then
        sEvent.strEventDetails += strText & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddToEventDetails(ByRef sEvent As My_GoogleEvent, strLabelID As String, ByRef dictLabels As Dictionary(Of String, String), strValue1 As String, strValue2 As String, strValue3 As String, strValue4 As String)
    Dim strFormatString = dictLabels(strLabelID)
    Dim strText = String.Format(strFormatString, strValue1, strValue2, strValue3, strValue4)

    If (strText <> "") Then
        sEvent.strEventDetails += strText & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddToEventDetails(ByRef sEvent As My_GoogleEvent, strLabelID As String, ByRef dictLabels As Dictionary(Of String, String), strValue1 As String, strValue2 As String, strValue3 As String, strValue4 As String, strValue5 As String)
    Dim strFormatString = dictLabels(strLabelID)
    Dim strText = String.Format(strFormatString, strValue1, strValue2, strValue3, strValue4, strValue5)

    If (strText <> "") Then
        sEvent.strEventDetails += strText & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub
```

They are very simple and work just fine. I just wondered if there is a simple approach that I do not know about where these functions can be merged into one?

As you can see the key differences are:

1. The number of `String` parameters.
2. The variables passed to the `String.Format` function.

Now, I realise that I can make the `String` parameters `optional` and default them to `""` and then maybe use a `if\else` ladder or `switch`. But is there any other approach for this kind of thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Overloading and optional parameters are your two choices. If you were to use optional parameters then you would specify `Nothing` as the default value rather than an empty `String`.  If you want no value then specify no value.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it further, you also have the option of using a `ParamArray`, although that means that the number of values passed could be zero or greater than five.

Comment: You could consider that `string.Format()` accepts an array as argument. Your strings could just be `Params() as String`. [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453542/how-to-get-values-from-textbox-to-place-holder-automatically?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Jimi That sounds interesting. Need to read up on this `ParamArray`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Incidentally, there is an &= operator, so you could make it look tidier with `sEvent.strEventDetails &= strText & vbCrLf`.